# maintaining session in directory traversal using php

Tags: php

i'm new to php ... i'm trying to maintain a session in a directory traversal script ... however every time i go to a sub directory my session variables are lost ...
right now my script looks something like -

```
start_session();          

//login and authenticate using functions in included scripts 
//(include(login.php);include(auth.php)) and set session variables accordingly  

if (session variable is set)
{
    //start the traversal script
}
```

so what i want to know is how can you manage a session in a directory traversal ....can anyone help me out here ...

Comment: It would be easier if you paste a structural summary of your script as code reference in your post(including session access related to your question).

Comment: You have to make sure the session id is kept when going to a sub directory (which I assume means calling another script). Make sure the session id is passed as get-variable or, better, as cookie. cf php.net/session

Comment: thx wonk0 but i'm not calling another script for going to a sub directory ... in fact i am recursively calling the same script with a query string specifying the directory ('?dir='.name of directory) ... when i pass a flag variable in the query string itself i can make the code work but when i try to store it in a session variable it gets lost ...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['directory_path'])) {
   $directory_path = $_SESSION['directory_path'];
} else {
   $directory_path = 'default/path';
}

// traverse with path

$_SESSION['directory_path'] = $new_directory_path;
```